# Add and Retrieve Audio

Tags: express, multer

I have added and retrived image in MongoDB using Node. Can I use the same code with some adjustment? Suggest me.

**upload.ts**

```
var multer = require("multer");
export let UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads";
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    req;
    file;
    cb(null, UPLOAD_PATH);
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    req;
    cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now() + ".jpg");
  }
});
export const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single("avatar");
```

**image.controller.ts**

```
Upload

this._model.findOne(
  { ["user"]: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id) },
  img => {
    upload(req, res, err => {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(null);
      } else {
        // Create a new image model and fill the properties
        let newImage = new Image();
        newImage.filename = req.file.filename;
        newImage.originalName = req.file.originalname;
        newImage.desc = req.body.desc;
        newImage.url =
          req.protocol + "://" + req.get("host") + "/images/" + newImage._id;
        newImage.user = user._id;
        newImage.save(err => {
          if (err) {
            res.status(400).json(null);
          } else {
            res.status(201).json(img);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
);

Retrive 

  getImage = (req, res) => {
    const user = this.getUser(req, res);
    this._model.findOne({ ['user']: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(user._id) }, (err, image) => {

      if (err) {
        res.status(500).json(null);
      }
      else if (image == null) {
        res.status(200).json(image);
      } else {
        // stream the image back by loading the file
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');
        fs.createReadStream(path.join(UPLOAD_PATH, image.filename)).pipe(res);
      }
    })
  };
```

Is it is possible to use same code with some modification to add and retrieve audio files using Node, Express in Mongo?

Comment: You could basically remove the "hard-coding" for `image/jpeg` and even file extensions. Multer creates a [`mimetype`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#api) property which you *"should"* be storing on the document and then using that value instead of the hard-coded string for `Content-Type`. The rest of the code is simply dumping files to disk or otherwise reading them from disk, and it's just binary stream transfers either way. Also, nothing really to do with "mongodb" since the "files" themselves are not being stored there.

Comment: can you explain in detail?